# how to access json file fields

Tags: php, json

```
{
 "took" : 363,
"timed_out" : false,
"num_reduce_phases" : 15,
"_shards" : {
"total" : 7195,
"successful" : 7195,
"failed" : 0
 },
"hits" : {
"total" : 35672,
"max_score" : 0.0,
"hits" : [ ]
},
"aggregations" : {
"2" : {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 54,
  "sum_other_doc_count" : 1463,
  "buckets" : [
    {
      "key" : "ふるさと納税",
      "doc_count" : 30376
    }
   ]
 }
 }
}
```

This is the json file . I need to access the doc_count field.

I am trying to do it  like this

```
$trend_words = json_decode($file);
$aggregations = $trend_words->aggregations;
$buckets = $aggregations->{2}->buckets->{0};
```

But its not working.
Can someone help.

Comment: The answers should work. A direct approach would be `$buckets = $aggregations->{2}->buckets[0];`. Curly brackets {} in json will be php objects (unless switched off), and you need `->`. Square brackets [] will be php arrays and you need `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$trend_words = json_decode($file,true);
$aggregations = $trend_words['aggregations']['2']['buckets'][0]['doc_count'];
print_r($aggregations)
```

You should use ,true otherwise you will get an stdclass object and not an array you want.

Comment: this works for single bucket. but not the multiple buckets.

Comment: The output of this code is 30376 i checked it.

Comment: try to add one more bucket in json. so that you will understand it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php

$sJson = '
{
 "took" : 363,
"timed_out" : false,
"num_reduce_phases" : 15,
"_shards" : {
"total" : 7195,
"successful" : 7195,
"failed" : 0
 },
"hits" : {
"total" : 35672,
"max_score" : 0.0,
"hits" : [ ]
},
"aggregations" : {
"2" : {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 54,
  "sum_other_doc_count" : 1463,
  "buckets" : [
    {
      "key" : "ふるさと納税",
      "doc_count" : 30376
    }
   ]
 }
 }
}
';

$aJson = json_decode($sJson, true);

echo $aJson['aggregations'][2]['buckets'][0]['doc_count'];
```

https://3v4l.org/kHfdo

Comment: this works for single bucket. but not the multiple buckets.

Comment: You are right Jinna, just to simplify the answer. You can make it more complex if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer, As the buckets increases you need to have a loop through to read all the buckets

```
$trend_words = json_decode($file, true);
$aggregations = $trend_words['aggregations'][2];
$buckets = array();
    foreach($aggregations as $element)
       $buckets[] = $element['buckets'];
    print_r($buckets);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Json to array and try

```
$trend_words = json_decode($file, true);
$aggregations = $trend_words['aggregations'];
$buckets =$aggregations[2]['buckets'][0];
```